# best way to synchronise a mail app with the server

Tags: php, javascript, android, ajax, synchronization

I am writing a mail application that synchronises all the mails in a user's gmail account.

I have implemented it using a function that make a request to the webservice for the mails, the service returns the latest 20 mails. Now from the last mail fetched, i am calling this function again. Basically its recursively fetching new mails.

Now this technique has many glitches

1. There are possibilities that a user deliberately closes the browser, hence there will be some mails gone missing from the app.
2. It is populating the client by queuing in too many requests making it impossible for me too make requests to other services with higher priority.

I want an efficient and better way than this. I have fruitlessly brainstormed a lot over this problem.

Comment: You're looking for IMAP.

Comment: not exactly, I am using imap in the backend webservice that sends 20 mails to the client everytime the client requests.